# akka how to to launch a master task and block on it finishing?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to get started with akka in scala. In the main scala thread I'd like to start an akka actor, send one message to it, and block until that actor terminates. What is the best way to do this?

For example I have a test actor that just repeatedly sends messages to itself:

```
class Incrementer() extends Actor {

  val maxMessages = 5
  var counter = 0

  def receive() = {
    case DoIncr() => {
      if (counter < maxMessages) {
        counter += 1
        self ! DoIncr()
      } else {
        self.stop()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and it is invoked via:

```
val inc = actorOf(new Incrementer()).start()
val result = inc !! DoIncr()
println(result) // this should block this thread, but it doesn't seem to.

// do other stuff
```

That block takes just over 5,000 ms to execute instead of what I expect to be a few ms, so it seems to have to do with a default future timeout - and the program does not actually terminate. All I'm really trying to do is time the performance of sending x number of messages. What's going on here?

Comment: You're not replying anything to the first DoIncr message (that you send in "inc !! DoIncr".

Comment: Thanks - if you have a chain of messages, clearly the first actor in that chain cannot reply to the main thread to unblock it until the last actor in the chain is processed. What is the best idiomatic way to do this in akka? Preferably the last actor in the chain is able to signal the main thread somehow as opposed to passing a message all the way back up the chain to the first actor.

Comment: Why do you want to block the main thread?

Comment: @viktor Well, I'm running multiple speed tests from the main thread and I don't want them to run at the same time. That seems orthogonal to the issue of how to have a chain of actors reply to the thread that initiated the chain though.

Comment: If you want to communicate with a thread you can use !!! and wait on the future if you need to block, or poll the future if you have other things to do in the mean time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Viktor mentioned, in order for `!!` to terminate successfully, you have to reply to the message.  The 5 second delay you are seeing the actor's default timeout, which is configurable.  More info can be found on the [Akka site](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1/scala/actors.html#send-messages).

If you use `forward` to send the message instead of `!`, then `self.reply` will respond to the original sender.

The first message you send to an Akka actor performs some setup that doesn't happen when processing other messages.  Be sure to take that into account for your timings.

Corrected code would be:

```
import akka.actor._

object DoIncr

class Incrementer extends Actor {
  val maxMessages = 5
  var counter = 0

  def receive = {
    case DoIncr =>
      if (counter < maxMessages) {
        counter += 1
        self forward DoIncr
      } else {
        self.reply(()) // replying with () since we have nothing better to say
        self.stop()
      }
  }
}
```

*Aside*: I made a few other changes to get your code in line with idiomatic Scala.  Your code works without these changes, but it now looks like more typical Scala code.

- Case classes without parameter lists have been deprecated.  Use `object`s instead.
- If you have a class without a parameter list, you can omit the parenthesis
- `Actor`'s `receive` method does not have parens; your implementing class shouldn't have them either.
- It's purely a matter of style, but the body of a `case` statement does not require braces.

Comment: sorry for the maybe stupid question: how do I import / where can I find more information on `!!`? I've googled around but didn't find much..